# Share custom ribbon with multiple add-ins (manifests)

Tags: office-js

I'm not sure if this is a bug or by design but I have two different add-ins (**different manifest files**) that I'm developing but I want them to use the same custom ribbon. Currently, it doesn't seem possible.

### **Expected:**

The user should be able to do the following:

1. Add the first add-in called "A1" (side-loaded or through store)
2. The Custom ribbon should appear with the name "Awesome Stuff" which has a group of various command buttons that are specific to addin A1.
3. The user should return a few weeks later and now wants to use add-in "A2" so insert this add-in (via side-loading or office store).
4. Office would then recognize that the manifest for A2 contains the same ID/Name for the custom ribbon and add the command buttons for A2 into the same custom ribbon created by A1. They would be side-by-side under different Groups.

### **Observing:**

It appears to me that the second add-in will create another tab with the same name and thus two separate manifest cannot share the same Custom Ribbon.

*Screenshots of what I'm seeing*

[image: Two Custom Tabs Created]
[image: Manifest with Same custom tab id]

### **Environment**

I'm using the latest Office Insiders of Excel (16.8 build 171111). I tested in Excel Online and same result.

### **Question**

- Is this by design or potentially a bug?
- Is there something wrong or missing from my manifest?
- I'm guessing the standard excel ribbons (main, insert, etc...) do not have this problem?

---

> **Why not use a single manifest?**
>
> Assuming the above is by design...The second add-in is additive features on top of the first manifest. All the users will be using the features of the first add-in but only certain users will be using the second add-in. If we including it in a single manifest it will confuse users that do not need it so ideally we would like them separate.

Comment: Is the bit at the end of your question really a quote? From where?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible currently. I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding this as a suggestion.

That said, there are some interesting concerns this would raise. It would open up the possibility for other add-ins to accidentally (or maliciously) break your add-in's commands/tab by inserting their own commands/tab with the same `id`.

A better option, based on the scenario you outlined, would be to support altering the ribbon at run time (there is an existing [UserVoice that speaks to this](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19026019-programmatically-disable-hide-the-ribbon-menu)). It sounds like the ability to add or enable/disable commands to the ribbon at run-time would allow you to provide everything in a single add-in.

Comment: Sadly, those UserVoice links are dead now.

Comment: Where can we track this feature in 2023?