# Share custom tab with two different excel-addins

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I have two different excel addins having **different manifest files**. I want to install them under the **same custom tab**.

I tried using same Ids for CustomTab and Group for both the manifest files whereas having different Ids for Control Tag. But this also didn't help me.

Interestingly, if I add both applications in the same manifest file, they appear under the same CustomTab.

The same issue has been raised back in 2017. Not sure if we can do it now.
[Share custom ribbon with multiple add-ins (manifests)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47331908/share-custom-ribbon-with-multiple-add-ins-manifests)

Appreciate any advise on what I might have missed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported. You can make this suggestion at [Office developer suggestion box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) or vote it up if it has already been made.

**UPDATE 1/3/22:** The new place to suggest improvements is the [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform)

Comment: Link is dead. More I try to test my deployment the more beta this software feels, but I've been using VBA which has been around a long time. Still, please work on deployment fix's before code improvements.

Comment: Only 1 task pane per add-in, but can't share tabs? I have currently probably 5 tabs w/ like 30 buttons in 1 file via `xlam`. How am I supposed to migrate this to `Office.JS`? 20 tabs?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Rick ! Do u know if there's something already posted about sharing custom tabs that I could vote on? Or is that not how it works?

Comment: I don't know. I think you'll have to search the site.