# how to add multiple excel add-ins on same custom tab in yo office excel add-ins

Tags: javascript, excel, ms-office, office-js, excel-addins

I'm new to the new Excel Add Ins. I have created two excel Addin with the node yo generator, and in the manifest  file I have created a custom tab and on two project custom tab id is the same, but when it runs it will generate two tabs with the same name, but I want to show that two excel add-ins in same custom tab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share custom tab with two different excel-addins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64010374/share-custom-tab-with-two-different-excel-addins)